# Pagination error on Gatsby JS category and tag pages

Tags: gatsby-plugin

I use the awesome paginate plugin for Gatsby to do pagination on archive pages on the site. The plugin connects to the gatsby-node file.js is called there with the help of such code

```
    paginate({
        createPage,
        items: allMdx.edges,
        itemsPerPage: 1,
        pathPrefix: '/work',
        component: path.resolve('src/templates/work.js')
    });
```

Pagination works great on blog and works pages. I created these pages using the Gatsby Route API, without using the createPage function in gatsby-node. Pagination works great on blog and works pages. I created these pages using the Gatsby Route API, without using the createPage function in gatsby-node.js . But on the pages of tags and categories, I can't enable pagination. These pages were created using createPage. Below I present the code of my gatsby-node.js

```
const _ = require("lodash")
//const readingTime = require("reading-time")
const { paginate } = require('gatsby-awesome-pagination')
const path = require("path")
const { transliterate } = require('./src/functions/transletter')
const { createFilePath } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem')


/* Create category page */
function dedupeCategories(allMdx) {
    const uniqueCategories = new Set()
    // Iterate over all articles
    allMdx.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      // Iterate over each category in an article
      node.frontmatter.categories.forEach(category => {
        uniqueCategories.add(category)
      })
    })
    // Create new array with duplicates removed
    return Array.from(uniqueCategories)
}

/* Create tag page */
function dedupeTags(allMdx) {
    const uniqueTags = new Set()
    // Iterate over all articles
    allMdx.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      // Iterate over each category in an article
      node.frontmatter.tags.forEach(tag => {
        uniqueTags.add(tag)
      })
    })
    // Create new array with duplicates removed
    return Array.from(uniqueTags)
}


exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions

    // Query markdown files including data from frontmatter
    const {
      data: { allMdx },
    } = await graphql(`
      query {
        allMdx (filter: {frontmatter: {type: {in: "blog"}}}){
          edges {
            node {
              id
              frontmatter {
                categories
                tags
                slug
              }
              fields {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)

    // Create array of every category without duplicates
    const dedupedCategories = dedupeCategories(allMdx)
    // Iterate over categories and create page for each
    dedupedCategories.forEach(category => {
      reporter.info(`Creating page: blog/category/${category}`)
      createPage({
        path: `blog/category/${_.kebabCase(transliterate(category))}`,
        component: require.resolve("./src/templates/categories.js"),
        // Create props for our CategoryList.js component
        context: {
          category,
          // Create an array of ids of articles in this category
          ids: allMdx.edges
            .filter(({ node }) => {
              return node.frontmatter.categories.includes(category)
            })
            .map(({node}) => node.id),
        },
      })
    })

    // Create array of every category without duplicates
    const dedupedTags = dedupeTags(allMdx)
    // Iterate over categories and create page for each
    dedupedTags.forEach(tag => {
      reporter.info(`Creating page: blog/tag/${tag}`)
      createPage({
        path: `blog/tag/${_.kebabCase(transliterate(tag))}`,
        component: require.resolve("./src/templates/tags.js"),
        // Create props for our CategoryList.js component
        context: {
          tag,
          // Create an array of ids of articles in this category
          ids: allMdx.edges
            .filter(({ node }) => {
              return node.frontmatter.tags.includes(tag)
            })
            .map(({node}) => node.id),
        },
      })
    })


/* It's creating a new page for each post. */
    paginate({
        createPage,
        items: allMdx.edges,
        itemsPerPage: 1,
        pathPrefix: '/blog',
        component: path.resolve('src/templates/blog.js')
    });

/* It's creating a new page for each post. */
    paginate({
        createPage,
        items: allMdx.edges,
        itemsPerPage: 1,
        pathPrefix: '/work',
        component: path.resolve('src/templates/work.js')
    });

    /* It's creating a new page for each post. */
    paginate({
        createPage,
        items: allMdx.edges,
        itemsPerPage: 1,
        pathPrefix: '/blog/category',
        component: path.resolve('src/templates/categories.js')
    });


}

/* Creating a slug for each post. */
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
    const { createNodeField } = actions;
    if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
      const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode });

      createNodeField({
        name: 'slug',
        node,
        value,
      });
    }
  };


/* It's creating a new field in the GraphQL schema called `relatedPosts` that returns an array of Mdx
nodes. */
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
    const resolvers = {
        Mdx: {
        relatedPosts: {
          type: ['Mdx'],
          resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
            return context.nodeModel.runQuery({
              query: {
                filter: {
                  id: {
                    ne: source.id,
                  },
                  frontmatter: {
                    // type: {
                    //  ne: source.frontmatter.type === `work`,
                    // },
                    tags: {
                      in: source.frontmatter.tags,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              type: 'Mdx',
            })
          },
        },
      },
    }

    createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```

And this is the template code of my category `src/templates/category.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Seo from '../components/seo'
import Pager from '../components/pagination'

const CategoryList = ({ pageContext: { category }, data: { allMdx }, pageContext }) =>
(
    <Layout pageTitle={category}>
        {
            allMdx.edges.map(({ node }) => {
                return (
                    <article key={node.id}>
                        <h2>
                            <Link to={`/blog${node.fields.slug}`}>
                            {node.frontmatter.title}
                            </Link>
                        </h2>
                        <p>Posted: {node.frontmatter.date}</p>
                        <p>{node.excerpt}</p>
                    </article>
                )
            })
        }
    <Pager pageContext={pageContext} />
  </Layout>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query CategoryListQuery($ids: [String]!, $limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
    allMdx (filter: { id: { in: $ids },  frontmatter: {type: {in: "blog"}}}, limit: $limit,
    skip: $skip) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
          fields {
            slug
          }
          id
          excerpt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`



export const Head = ({ pageContext }) => (
    <Seo
        title={pageContext.category}
        description={`Статьи из категории ${pageContext.category}`}
    />
)

export default CategoryList
```

The Pager component looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const Pager = ({ pageContext }) => {
  const { previousPagePath, nextPagePath } = pageContext;
  return (
    <nav style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <div>
        {previousPagePath && (
          <Link to={previousPagePath}>
            <button>← Newer Posts</button>
          </Link>
        )}
      </div>

      <div style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-end' }}>
        {nextPagePath && (
          <Link to={nextPagePath}>
            <button>Older Posts →</button>
          </Link>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Pager;
```

This is errors

```
ERROR #85920  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Variable "$limit" of required type "Int!" was not provided.

>  1 | query CategoryListQuery($ids: [String]!, $limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
     |                                          ^
   2 |   allMdx(
   3 |     filter: {id: {in: $ids}, frontmatter: {type: {in: "blog"}}}
   4 |     limit: $limit
   5 |     skip: $skip
   6 |   ) {
   7 |     edges {
   8 |       node {
   9 |         frontmatter {
  10 |           title
  11 |           date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")

File path: C:/gatsby/schtml/src/templates/categories.js
Url path: /blog/category/gatsby-js
Plugin: none

Suggestion 1:

If you're not using a page query but a useStaticQuery / StaticQuery you see this error because they currently don't support
variables. To learn more about the limitations of useStaticQuery / StaticQuery, please visit these docs:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/

Suggestion 2:

You might have a typo in the variable name "$limit" or you didn't provide the variable via context to this page query. Have a look  
at the docs to learn how to add data to context:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query


 ERROR #85920  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Variable "$skip" of required type "Int!" was not provided.

>  1 | query CategoryListQuery($ids: [String]!, $limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
     |                                                        ^
   2 |   allMdx(
   3 |     filter: {id: {in: $ids}, frontmatter: {type: {in: "blog"}}}
   4 |     limit: $limit
   5 |     skip: $skip
   6 |   ) {
   7 |     edges {
   8 |       node {
   9 |         frontmatter {
  10 |           title
  11 |           date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")

File path: C:/gatsby/schtml/src/templates/categories.js
Url path: /blog/category/gatsby-js
Plugin: none

Suggestion 1:

If you're not using a page query but a useStaticQuery / StaticQuery you see this error because they currently don't support
variables. To learn more about the limitations of useStaticQuery / StaticQuery, please visit these docs:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/

Suggestion 2:

You might have a typo in the variable name "$skip" or you didn't provide the variable via context to this page query. Have a look at the docs to learn how to add data to context:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query


 ERROR #85920  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Variable "$limit" of required type "Int!" was not provided.

>  1 | query CategoryListQuery($ids: [String]!, $limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
     |                                          ^
   2 |   allMdx(
   3 |     filter: {id: {in: $ids}, frontmatter: {type: {in: "blog"}}}
   4 |     limit: $limit
   5 |     skip: $skip
   6 |   ) {
   7 |     edges {
   8 |       node {
   9 |         frontmatter {
  10 |           title
  11 |           date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")

File path: C:/gatsby/schtml/src/templates/categories.js
Url path: /blog/category/gatsby-develop
Plugin: none

Suggestion 1:

If you're not using a page query but a useStaticQuery / StaticQuery you see this error because they currently don't support
variables. To learn more about the limitations of useStaticQuery / StaticQuery, please visit these docs:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/

Suggestion 2:

You might have a typo in the variable name "$limit" or you didn't provide the variable via context to this page query. Have a look  
at the docs to learn how to add data to context:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query


 ERROR #85920  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Variable "$skip" of required type "Int!" was not provided.

>  1 | query CategoryListQuery($ids: [String]!, $limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
     |                                                        ^
   2 |   allMdx(
   3 |     filter: {id: {in: $ids}, frontmatter: {type: {in: "blog"}}}
   4 |     limit: $limit
   5 |     skip: $skip
   6 |   ) {
   7 |     edges {
   8 |       node {
   9 |         frontmatter {
  10 |           title
  11 |           date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")

File path: C:/gatsby/schtml/src/templates/categories.js
Url path: /blog/category/gatsby-develop
Plugin: none

Suggestion 1:

If you're not using a page query but a useStaticQuery / StaticQuery you see this error because they currently don't support
variables. To learn more about the limitations of useStaticQuery / StaticQuery, please visit these docs:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/

Suggestion 2:

You might have a typo in the variable name "$skip" or you didn't provide the variable via context to this page query. Have a look at the docs to learn how to add data to context:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query

success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.044s - 2/2 45.97/s
success run page queries - 0.422s - 3/3 7.12/s
success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.059s - 3/3 50.83/s
```